# How can I enable the old HTML5 browser notifications?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, notifications

I have two computers, both running Windows 10, sitting right next to one another. When notifications come from my browser on Computer 1, it's in a nice little unassuming grey box. On Computer 2, the Windows notification center instead throws up a rather large notification box that doesn't properly go away once the browser receives focus again.

For context, the application triggering these notifications is the Google Hangouts Chrome extension on both machines. Both machines are using Chrome version 93+.

I would very much like to force Computer 2 to use the notifications currently on Computer 1.

Computer 1 notification image:

[image]

Computer 2 notification image:

[image]

Comment: Do both PC's have the same build of windows 10?

Comment: @Berend Computer 1 is on Win10 Enterprise, Version 1607, build 14393.2906. Computer 2 is on Win10 Education, Version 21H1, build 19043.1237.

Comment: That could very well explain the difference then, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history

Answer (score 0):

Computer 2 uses Brave, not Chrome, so the notification format is
different.

Uninstall Brave and install Chrome instead, to have the same
notifications format.

Comment: Brave uses Chromium, so it has the same notification base. Just to be sure, though, I have Chrome installed, and it still uses the Windows notification instead of browser notifications.

Comment: I've recreated the problem in Chrome and edited my post.

Comment: (1) Compare on both computers in Chrome the value of `chrome://flags/#enable-system-notifications`. Compare also all other settings on this page that contain the string "notifications". (2) In Windows, run *Settings > System > Notif‌ications & actions*, click Chrome and compare settings.

Comment: Regarding chrome://flags/#enable-system-notifications, both are set to Default, as are all other settings with "notification" in the title string.
These are slightly different versions of Windows (hopefully not enough to change notification behavior this drastically), but all settings that are in both versions are the same on each.

Comment: What do you mean by "slightly different versions of Windows"?

Comment: I saw your comment about the two Windows versions. They are not truly "slightly different".

Answer (score 0):

There is no way on Windows 10 21H1 to customize notifications or use the old browser notifications. Feedback submitted to Microsoft.